# JSP link to Another JSP file in a different Folder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am new to net beans and JSP. I created `index.jsp` in Web Pages folder and i want to link a text in `index.jps` to another JSP called `CompanyLogin.jsp` in `Web Pages/MainLogins/ComapanyLogins/CompanyLogin.jsp`.

I tried `<li><a href="/MainLogins/CompanyLogin/CompanyLogin.jsp">Company</a></li>`
but it didn't work. Plese tell me hoe to solve this problem. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash at the URL's beginning makes it absolute to your host. But usually the first part of the path is the context name. It's safest to use a relative path like

```
<a href="MainLogins/CompanyLogin/CompanyLogin.jsp">Company</a>
```

Here relative means relative to the location of index.jsp.